# acceptance of precision in research papers

Tags: computer-science, writing-style, errors-erratum

I am implementing a few numerical examples in MATLAB, and I am getting some solutions in which instead of getting exact value 0, I am getting a very small number, such as $10^{-6}$. This seems to be a very common problem [Here1](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/485500-why-is-matlab-giving-me-a-a-very-small-number-when-the-answer-should-be-exactly-zero), [Here2](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/385420-output-a-small-number-as-zero). 
So my doubt is, is there any standard rule for journal and conference papers, that states upto what precision we must consider the values. (like, in my example I want to consider it as 0, is it allowed)? Should I explicitly state in the paper that $10^{-6}$ is what I got, but I am considering it to be 0?

Comment: "Numerical examples" of what?

Comment: The required precision depends on what you're doing or claiming. Probably best to discuss this with your advisor.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I am solving an optimization problem (Cone programming problem), in which one of the solutions is 10^(-6), am I allowed to write it as 0?

Comment: Independent of what your research is about: As soon as you work with floating point numbers, there will be an error. Your responsibility should be to formulate the problem as good as possible (well-conditioned) and use methods that are numerically stable (if available). If you can ensure that, I think a disclaimer that the results are the best possible with respect to floating point arithmetic should be fine. You should not, however, manipulate computation logs and just replace small numbers with 0.

Comment: @Cherryblossoms Does the optimization function you're using have a configurable tolerance?  If so, is $10^{-6}$ of the order of the tolerance you've set?

Comment: Read this: Cole TJ. , "Too many digits: the presentation of numerical data", Arch Dis Child 2015;100:608–609. This paper has some nice rules of thumb.

Comment: @DanielHatton There is no configurable tolerance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right question to ask is 10^{-6} *what*? If you are determining the best trajectory for a space probe to get from Earth to Pluto, and you choose to measure distances in lightyears, then $10^{-6}$ is a very very large number definitely not equal to zero. But if you choose to measure distances in meters, then 10^{-6} is a very small distance and you can safely assume that it is zero. On the other hand, if you were dealing with atomic distances and measured in meters, then 10^{-6} is again not a small number at all.

In other words, it is all *relative* and there can be no answer independent of what the meaning of the corresponding variable is, what its units are, and how the number with units relate to the *typical values* of variables with these units in your setting.

Comment: Tysm for answering, it is really helpful. In my case, the solution is to be seen as a probability value. Could you please suggest, in this case, is it acceptable to treat it as 0? I am asking just to get an opinion. It would be great if you reply!

Comment: The same applies. If you are interested in the probability that it will rain today, then 10^{-6} is zero. If you are interested in the probability that the nuclear power plant next door will blow up today, then it isn't. It is all about context. Numbers only make sense in context.

Comment: Further note: even the very same quantity may need to be treated differently depending on the field. In most areas of physics, it does not really matter if the neutrino mass is 0.05 eV or exactly 0, however it is absurd to equate them if this is exactly what you're studying! So much so that this very problem has branched into a whole research field with a Nobel prize awarded for this specific thing (and some three more neutrino-related prior to that). So yes, the probability of rain being $10^{-6}$ might be =0 or extremely important, and it is up for you the researcher to tell whether it is.